# Logged out when returning a file but cancelling download

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I've got a simple action that returns a file from a database.

```
public ActionResult Download(int sbID)
    {
        var module = moduleRepo.Snackbar.First(m => m.Id == sbID);
        var data = moduleRepo.SnackbarData.First(m => m.Id == sbID).FileData;
        var filename = module.FileName + "." + module.FileType;

        return File(data, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, filename);
    }
```

Everything works fine, but when a user hit's the download button, and then hit's "Cancel" (instead of Save as or open) it seems like the session terminates, because the user logs out. I am using regular Microsoft Identity authentication.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you set up a test project that reproduces this?